# How do I get the column alias in Postgres in camelcase instead of lowercase, without using double quote?

Tags: postgresql

I have some ready mysql query that I want to convert into Postgres sql. But the problem is alise of column name Postgres return all name as lowercase format. I can use double quote but I have many query so its very costly. is there any way to get data in camel case instead of lowercase.

Comment: It's not possible, but why do you care?

Comment: I have lots of existing query. its a big problem to use double quote after each alise of selection.

Comment: But why do you care if the alias is `FooBar` or `foobar`?

Comment: The problem is when I try to set the result in any data grid in application then its make problem

Answer (score 4):

Like @a_horse_with_no_name said, for all practical purposes, it's impossible. I suppose you *could* download the source code, alter it to work the way you like, and recompile and test it. But I think that's a really, really bad idea.

On the database side, you have two sensible options.

- Replace MySQL's backticks with nothing.
- Replace MySQL's backticks with double quotes.

Say you start with this in MySQL.

```
create table `Test` (
  `TestId` integer primary key,
  `TestName` varchar(35) not null
);

create or replace view `TestAll` as
select `TestId`, `TestName` 
from `Test`;
```

Replace all backticks with nothing. Run this in PostgreSQL.

```
create table Test (
  TestId integer primary key,
  TestName varchar(35) not null
);

create or replace view TestAll as
select TestId, TestName 
from Test;
```

PostgreSQL will fold all the identifers to lowercase. Everything will just work.  (Unless perhaps you're using reserved words. Always a bad idea.)

Second alternative, replace backticks with double quotes.

```
create table "Test" (
  "TestId" integer primary key,
  "TestName" varchar(35) not null
);

create or replace view "TestAll" as
select "TestId", "TestName"
from "Test";
```

PostgreSQL preserves case for delimited identifiers. Everything still works.

The way you choose will probably have something to do with how your application code is written. Web frameworks like Rails, Laravel, and Django generate delimited identifers throughout. (I think that's probably true for all web frameworks; it's the safest way to generate SQL.) Other programs might or might not use delimited identifiers, and they can be more or less trouble to convert.

---

If you have a MySQL dump file in text format, you can replace every backtick with double quotes using this `sed` one-liner.

```
$ sed -i -e 's/`/"/g' mysql_dump.file
```

Replace every backtick with nothing this way.

```
$ sed -i -e 's/`//g' mysql_dump.file
```

This way, `sed` will modify the file in-place, without making a backup. Use `man sed` for more options.

Comment: 333333333333tsddoo